# Add multiple databases (instead of one) to an existing application

Tags: java, database, dependency-injection

We are using Mongo Db as a database.

If we got the following JAX-RS service (or some other Stateless/Statefull EJB).

```
@Path("my_service_path")
@Stateless
public class GetSomeObject{

  @Inject
  public DB database;

  @GET
  @Consumes("application/json")
  @Produces("application/json")
  public SomeDomainObject get(@QueryParam("some_param") String param){
  ...
  database.find(...);
  ...
  return something;
  }
}
```

The PROBLEM: We need to use two or more databases, but in our current source it seems impossible. We are currently using injected DBs, but if we were using `EntityManager` implementation or something other we would meet the same problem. Are there some integrated solutions for injecting different instances of a class, depending of user/application. We can try

```
  @Inject
  public Map<String, DB> databases;
```

but we must add too many conditional logic to handle these maps of databases.

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to do this in a DI framework is via qualifiers. If you are using CDI then you would accomplish this via a combination of producers and qualifier annotations. I find this a good method for selecting one a few instances that are known at compile time. If you need to retrieve instances based on run time information then you may need to use a Factory.

For CDI, here is some pseudocode:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, TYPE})
public @interface PrimaryDatabase {
}

@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, TYPE})
public @interface SecondaryDatabase {
}

public class DatabaseProducer {

   @Produces
   @PrimaryDatabase
   public DB getPrimaryDB() {
      // ...
   }

   @Produces
   @SecondaryDatabase
   public DB getSecondayDB() {
      // ...
   }
}

public class GetSomeObject{

  @Inject
  @PrimaryDatabase
  public DB primaryDB;

  @Inject
  @SecondaryDatabase
  public DB secondaryDB;
}
```